# Trying to find the number of unique values in an array but it always equals 0

Tags: c++

In my main function I call these two functions.
My duplicate value function works, it tells the user how many duplicate values there are. However, my unique value function always tells the user that there are 0 unique values. Obviously that's false because the first value is always unique.

I tried using my debugger and looking up the solution for my problem but the debugger isn't helping me to my knowledge.

Finding unique values function

```
short count_distinct(short num[], short size)   //Function to return the count of the number of unique/distinct values in the array
{
short i, j, unique=0;
for(i=0;i<size;i++) 
{
    for(j=0;j<size;j++) //nested for statement which goes through the array to compare with previous numbers
    {
        if (num[i]==num[j]) //compares the numbers to eachother
        {
            break; // if they are equal then dont count it

        }
    if(i==j)
        unique++;
    }
}
return unique;
}
```

finding duplicate values function

```
short count_duplicates(short num[], short size) //Function to return the count of the number of duplicate values in the array
{
short i, j, count =0;
for( i=1;i<size;i++) //start 1 high to compare to previous numbers
{
    for(j=0;j<i;j++) //nested for statement which goes through the array to compare with previous numbers
    {
        if (num[i]==num[j]) //compares the numbers to eachother
        {
        count++;    // if values are equal they are duplicates
        break;
        }
    }

}

return count;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try this out:

```
short count_distinct(short num[], short size)   //Function to return the count of the number of unique/distinct values in the array
{
    short i, j, unique=0;
    for(i=0;i<size;i++) 
    {
        short same = 0;
        for(j=0;j<size;j++) //nested for statement which goes through the array to compare with previous numbers
        {
            if (num[i]==num[j]) //compares the numbers to eachother
            {
                same++;
            }
        }
        if (same == 1)
        {
            unique++;
        }
    }
    return unique;
}
```

It just checks how many of the same elements there are in the entire array, and if there's only one of it in the entire array, then it's unique.

Comment: I ran it with a short array of {1,2,3} and size 3, and I got 3 in return. I also tried {1,1,3}, size 3 and got 1. What did you run it with?

Comment: You are correct, my compiler had malfunctioned so I reinstalled it and my original code was actually correct lol.

Comment: Woops. My mistake, I probably should've just directly tried out your code first. Perhaps you could just add your own answer then and accept that or just accept mine? :D

Answer (score 0):

The `if (i==j)` statement will never run because whenever i==j, num[i] and num[j] will be the same and the loop will break before you can increment the counter.

Comment: I see, but how can I make it increment then? Im lost, this is what my professor told me to do

Comment: There are several ways to deal with it. One pretty simple way is to just mark the values that are repeated and after everything is marked, you just count the ones that are not. This is probably the most inefficient solution, but the easiest to code. Another solution is whenever you find duplicates, swap both with positions i and i+1, then increment a duplicate counter and increment i+2. The inner loop would have j=i+1. Return size - duplicates. This way you would avoid counting a value twice or counting a duplicated value as a unique. These are the easier solutions to code that I can think of.